# NSDateFormatter returns null values dateFromString: iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, nsstring, nsdate, nsdateformatter

Am working in iPhone app. Am getting date from webservice response. When am receive the date i am storing in NSArray. And when i change the NSString to NSDate the date returns null. Here is my code,

```
  for (int k = 0; k<[dateArray count]; k++)  
 {
    NSString *dateStr = [dateArray objectAtIndex:k];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter1 setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"]; 
    [dateFormatter1 setFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehaviorDefault];
    [dateFormatter1 setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
    NSLog(@"DateStr : %@", dateStr); //Console Output is : 2012-07-09 13:50:07 [For 42nd and above values]
    NSDate *date = [dateFormatter1 dateFromString:dateStr];
    NSLog(@"Date : %@", date); // Console Output is : (null) [For 42nd and above values]
 }
```

The dateArray contains 43 date values from Webservice. The `NSDateFormatter returns correct NSDate from NSString til 41nd values`. When the `42nd string passing to the NSDateFormatter the output returns "(null)".` I have tried when the date returns null again i have convert the dateFromString again the `"(null)"` error occuring. Can anyone please help me to solve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the string in the 42nd value? Have you checked that it is a valid date and in the correct format?

Comment: @NickBull Thanks. This is the string from an array "2012-07-09 13:50:07". I have taken this value and converted to NSDate used the same NSDateFormatter in other place in the class. It returns the exact NSDate. It is valid. Could you please help me to solve this? Thanks.

Comment: Add `NSLog(@"DateStr : %@", dateStr);` in the line before `NSDate *date = [dateFormatter1 dateFromString:dateStr];` and then edit your question with the console output

Comment: Try using the `getObjectValue:forString:range:error:` on NSDateFormatter and then examine the error for a reason

Comment: Lemme guess:  The 42nd value is the first one with an hour value greater than 12.

Comment: Just a tip, if you want to speed things up create the `NSDateFormatetr` out side of the loop and only call the `dateFromString:` inside the look.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try using capital 'HH' instead of 'hh'.  hh is hours 1-12,  HH is hours 0-23 - maybe the 13:00 is throwing it?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have fixed the issue. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the same `NSDateFormatter` everywhere, and iterating through a `forin` loop.  You are leaking a ton of memory the way you are using now.  I can't guarantee that this will fix your problem, but at least it will clean up your code.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"]; 

for (NSString *dateString in dateArray) {
    NSLog (@"Date %@ and index %i: NSDate representation is %@", dateString, [dateArray indexOfObject:dateString], [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString]);
}
```

If this doesn't solve your problem, keep in mind a couple of things:

1. Don't set the `timeZone` on your date formatter.  The strings don't contain a time zone so it won't do anything.
2. Don't set the `formatterBehavior` either.  It is automatically `NSDateFormatterBehaviorDefault`.
3. Make sure that there is nothing inherently different about the first 41 dates and the rest.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have fixed the issue from Mr.Gamozzii's answer. Thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

you use "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss" format instead of "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

hh is hours 1-12, HH is hours 0-23 .You got hours in 0-23 format.

[dateFormatter1 setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];